# calling functions from different forms - visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

I'm writing a project that has multiple forms. both of the forms need to be able to perform the same function, but only one form is capable of doing it due to the layout. Is it possible to open the other form, launching the function straight away, and then returning to the original form with the outcome of the function as a variable?

The function turns a grid of buttons on one of the forms into a keyboard for touch typing. (only one form has the correct button layout to do this)

Comment: Are either of the forms launched from a parent form or are you detecting which form to display when the application launches?

Answer (score 0):

Without an example of your function or views I can't be more specific, however I think the issue here is your design - doing this in a [MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx) or [MVVM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) model is relatively simple to achieve.

***Note:*** While most, if not all, examples for these patterns will be in ASP.Net and XAML it is still just as applicable to winforms.

The first and most important thing you need to do is to separate out the logic of this function from the view - either a controller class or helper class.

This way the function can be performed from multiple views without the need to instantiate or display the view it is currently tied to.

If there is view-specific logic in the function (e.g. _view.MyButton.Text = "Push Me") then you need to separate this out further. You only want the function to perform the logic it needs and then pass it's results back to which ever view called it - let the view handle stuff like text assignment.

It may seem like over-engineering but it is cleaner and more maintainable.